# window.location.href Loads WHOLE URL When INCOMPLETE URL Input is Submitted by Form

Tags: javascript, forms, window.location

When text is entered into this form, it then loads a webpage with that typed text appended at the end of my domain name, to create the full page url. (Incidentally, it also disables the typed Enter key to submit, because I only want the clicked Submit button to submit the form.)

It works, but too well. Weirdly, I can type “ann” and be directed to mysite.com/annex. Worse yet, typing in “an” directs me to mysite.com/anabelle for example … it's defaulting to whichever existing page is first in alphabetical order (ana comes before ann). How do I limit this behavior, so users must type the ENTIRE word or else go to a 404 error?

```
<!-- Location Input Form ENTER Button Disabler. Prevents ENTER from submitting form. See also in body form: onkeypress="return noenter()" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function noenter() {
  return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); }
</script>

<!-- Location Input Form Script, entered location must match url's "/folder" since it's appended to the domain name. For alts, add a redirect to HTACCESS -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function noenter() {
       return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); }
    function buttonClick(){
      var url = document.getElementById("inputURL").value;
      window.location.href = "mysite.com/" + url;
      }
</script>

<!-- Location Input Form -->
<form>
<div class=formfieldcontainer>
<input class="formfield" onkeypress="return noenter()" type="text" id="inputURL" name="inputURL" value="">
</div>
<input class="submitbutton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonClick()">
</form>
```

I need users to have to type the ENTIRE word to access a page, not just the first few letters. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem like behavior of the provided JavaScript code that is doing the partial-match redirect, but rather your system that handles web requests.

Comment: Agreeing with @Wongjin... What if you just browse to http://example.com/an or http://example.com/ann do those also get you to pages as opposed to 404s?

Comment: You're right … typing example.com/ann in the browser goes to a page. Obviously something else is going on. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Woot! After banging my head on this for hours, your hint directed me to the solution in about 15min. 

Checked my HTACCESS and WordPress settings again, but still didn't find anything suspicious. Then a web search turned up the fact that "Partial Match Redirection" is default in WordPress now. There's a filter you can put into your functions.php to stop it: 

add_filter( 'do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false');

Documented here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-redirects-for-nonexistent-urls